# JSP/JSTL тэг <c:url не видит методы контроллера

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

Всем доброй ночи, изучаю Spring MVC + Hibernate по видеоурокам. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Мне нужно создать ссылку на метод контроллера и передать в нее параметр, но тэг <c:url> в value не видит методы моего контроллера, которые уже замаплены и при том в других страницах успешно используются. Почему то видит только jsp страницы с проекта.
(Хотя когда танцевал с бубном, узнал, что <a href эти методы видит, но он мне не подходит)

JSP

```
<input type="button" value="Update"
                onclick="window.location.href = '${updatebutton}'">
```

```
<c:url value="/updateInfo" var="updatebutton">
<c:param name="empsId" value="${emp.id}"> </c:param>
</c:url>
```

MyController

```
   @RequestMapping("/updateInfo")
   public String updateEmployee(@RequestParam("empId") int id, Model model){
       Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployee(id);
       model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
   return "employeeInfo";
   }
```

Comment: Удалось решить проблему?
Столкнулся с такой же, ничего не нашел(

Comment: @ShanghaiVibe не получилось, я сделал костыль - отдельную страницу для обновления юзера либо могу посоветовать перейти на thymeleaf и переписать страницы в html, в нем все это пишется почти так же, инфы в инете полно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл альтернативу, не как у Заурчика.

```
<c:url var="updateButton" value="http://localhost:8080/spring_course_mvc_hibernate_aop/updateInfo">
            <c:param name="empId" value="${emp.id}"/>
        </c:url>
```

Получается, нужно указать полный путь, а не просто `/updateInfo`. Полный путь можно посмотреть в "Edit Configurations", а там строка URL. После этого заработало.

У вас еще в строке `<c:param name="empsId" value="${emp.id}"> </c:param>` нужно в конце убрать `</c:param>`.
Чтобы было `<c:param name="empId" value="${emp.id}"/>`